# Encoding 25mp video

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, h.264, video-processing, libavcodec

I have a 25MP uncompressed video file of 100 frames.

I tried to encode it with ffmpeg and h264 encoder into a .mp4 file, but the encoding got stuck around the 10th frame.
This is the script:

```
avconv -y -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 5000K -pass 1 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 5000K -f mp4 /dev/null && \
avconv -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -preset medium -b:v 5000K -pass 2 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 5000K output.mp4
```

I am running it on a jetson TK1 with nvidia gpu, is there any way to use an accelarating encoding in order to make the encoding possible?

Please, if you can, give me a sampler script of something that might work.
Right now, I dont care how much time the encoding take, as long as it will work.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Normal Kepler architecture GPUs have hardware h264 encoding support. FFmpeg can be built with `--enable-nvenc` option to access nvenc encoder. However I don't know whether TK1 platform works.

Comment: I tried to run the encoding with this flag now, but it is still got killed around the 12-11th frame.
Do you know what may be the problem?

Comment: Show the full console output. In any case, that's not ffmpeg. Upgrade from [here](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html).